# Checkbox selected Issue

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am working on checkbox in ipad. i want to disable the checkbox and by default it is selected.

```
[checkboxButton1 setSelected:TRUE];
[checkboxButton1 setEnabled:FALSE];
```

If i use the above code, checkbox is getting disabled but it is not selected by default.

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: What class is checkBoxButton1 an instance of?

Comment: Who upvotes such careless, meaningless questions?

Answer (score 0):

A `UISwitch` has an `on` property. There's no checkbox in Cocoa Touch.